# How to change the total amount?

Tags: flutter, dart

I’m building a shop app and i have many products, I want to put an offer that when the user put an order for 2 pieces of the same product he get the third one for free, so he put 3 in the cart but the total amount is for 2, the same if he ordered 3,6,9,.....

this var is for the total price, the counter is the quantity

```
double usedPrice = getCurrentProduct.isOnSale
        ? getCurrentProduct.salePrice
        : double.parse(getCurrentProduct.price);
    double totalPrice = usedPrice * int.parse(counter.toString());
```

Comment: calculation for usedPrice is okay ? if yes. then make total price =
 usedPrice * (counter - ((counter/3).ceil()))

Comment: that Didn’t work

Answer (score 1):

After calculating `totalPrice` you can just update the quantity by

```
  counter = counter + (counter / 2).floor() ;
```

Comment: you mean to update it with set state ?

Comment: Yeah i mean if you want to show it to users

Comment: it didn’t work,it started to increment the wrong way

Comment: I dont really see how that would not work. Just try it out on dartpad with different values to see if it yields desired output or not